# Unable to connect to hosted site on IIS after opening it first time from the remote location

Tags: iis-10

I have deployed a web application ON IIS 10 on windows server 2016. The web application accessible from locally but When access it from remote location it accessible only first time and then un-accessible.

Moreover, the RDP is also not get through. Which mean the server will not accept any connection. I am unable to find the problem in the request. However the site is accessible locally.

Comment: Try pinging it from the remote location. Also, check with your host or your IT department to see if there is a firewall that could be interfering with your traffic.

Comment: did you get any error when try to access the site remotely? make sure management service and site both are in strat mode. try to open TCP Port of your site: open firewall setting -> Inbound Role -> Add New Role -> Choose Port -> Set Port -> and Allow, and ok

Comment: Thanks to All

Thanks Jalpa Panchal, the solution worked.